# Toggle autocorrectionType on and off (UITextView)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, autocorrect

I have a UITextView for which I want to be able to toggle the autocorrectionType.

Simply toggling the autocorrectionType like this does not work.

```
myTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
myTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

I've used

```
myTextView.text = myTextView.text;
```

and

```
[myTextView insertText:@" "];
[myTextView deleteBackward];
```

and

```
[myTextView setNeedsDisplay];
```

None of these work...

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say "it does not work". What does it do and what are you expecting it to do.

Comment: when UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo the text stays with the red dots underlined...i want to remove it.. i'm also doing this textContainerView.autocorrectionType=UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textContainerView.spellCheckingType=UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo;

Comment: The first big of code you wrote is correct. It sounds like more of an issue of where you're putting it.

Answer (score 1):

When you change such properties (including the type of keyboard), you often have to "kick start" the process

```
// Original
myTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
```

... // time goes by

```
// Now want to change
myTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
BOOL bogusKeyboardMotion = YES; // ivar
[myTextView resignFirstResponder];
[myTextView becomeFirstResponder];
bogusKeyboardMotion= NO;
```

Then ignore any delegate messages in your delegate methods. Maybe setting the delegate to nil then setting it back works too.

Comment: when i change these proprieties the keyboard is not first responder so it's not because of that. These options are in a new viewcontroller so the keyboard is always resigned... see my answer..